# What will come in place of question mark 10 , 6 , 8, 15, 34 ,?

Tags: number-sequence

I can't figure
 out what will come next in the sequence $10,6,8,15,34,...$ . 
I am thinking everything, but cannot seem to find a pattern.
Any hints please...

Comment: Where did this come from?

Comment: @JulianRosen You should not ask this it is cheat

Comment: Yes you are right, everything could come next in this (or any) sequence.

Comment: @JulianRosen After some searching, I have found that this question appears to have come from the State Bank of India's officer recruitment preliminary exam of July 3, 2016.

Comment: @f'' Yes it did come from there

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One possible solution:  The sequence follows the pattern

> $10\times  0.5+1=6$
>  $6\times 1+2=8$
>  $8\times 1.5+3=15$
>  $15\times 2+4=34$

The formula seems to be :

> $x_{n}= x_{n-1} * \frac{n}{2}+n $
>  with $x_0 = 10$

So the next term is

> $34\times 2.5+5=90.$

Answer (score 10):

$\left(\frac{10}2+1\right) \times 1 = 6$
$\left(\frac62+1\right) \times 2 = 8$ 
$\left(\frac82 + 1\right) \times 3= 15$ 
$\left(\frac{15}2 + 1\right) \times 4 = 34$
$\left(\frac{34}2 + 1\right) \times 5 = 90$

Comment: How is this any different than the other answer?

Comment: One fewer variable term per line

Comment: No decimal points in this answer

Comment: Also not in spoiler tag.